# how to add javascript in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

i want to add javaScript in the innerHTML

for example:-

```
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=('  <script type="text/javascript">
                LSM_Slot({
                adkey: 'a49',
                ad_size: '728x90',
                slot: 'slot124306'
                });
                </script> ');
```

i want to add the below code in the innerHTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                LSM_Slot({
                adkey: 'a49',
                ad_size: '728x90',
                slot: 'slot124306'
                });
                </script>
```

Comment: can you eval this ? --   <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
                    LSM_Slot({
                    adkey: 'a49',
                    ad_size: '728x90',
                    slot: 'slot124306'
                    });
                    //]]>
                    </script>

Comment: Why do you want to insert a script tag? i.e., why not just dynamically execute this LSM_Slot() method?

Comment: the above script is a ad tag ... but ad is not showing with LSM_Slot()  method